# How can I request the user to select five or less variables to define?

Tags: java, netbeans, logic

I'm having trouble understanding an assignment problem, specifically the problem asks me to create five integers... but I'd like to implement a way to make it 5 or less, if the user chooses. How can I do this? I apologize, I'm new to Java.

```
package realestatepropvalue;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class RealEstatePropertyValue
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner ( System.in );        
    System.out.println ( "Hello friend, you will enter a series "
            + "of fields that'll calculate your Real Estate Property Value.");

    System.out.print ("Please enter a Street Number ");
    String streetnum = sc.next();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("You entered the Street Number, " +streetnum );

    System.out.print ( "Please enter a Street Name ");
    String streetnam = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("You entered the Street Name, " + streetnam +   " " );

    System.out.print ("Please enter the number of rooms! (Up to 5!) ");

    int roomcount = sc.nextInt();

    String[] places = new String[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        places[i] = "Place Number: " + i;
        }

        sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("You said that there were " + roomcount + " rooms!");

    System.out.print ("Please enter the types of rooms (up to " +roomcount+ ") that fill up the " + roomcount + " rooms!\n"
            + "(Rooms like Living, Dining, Bedroom1-2, Kitchen, Bathroom, etc!) \n ") ;
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: `String[] places = new String[roomcount];` You should also make an if statement to check if `roomcount <= 5`.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the input in a loop until you meet the requirements you are looking for and then set the size of your array to the input:

```
System.out.print ("Please enter the number of rooms! (Up to 5!) ");

while(true){
    roomCount = sc.nextInt();
    if(roomCount <= 5 && roomCount > 0){
        break;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid amount of rooms");
    }
}

String[] places = new String[roomCount];
```